# encoding problems from text file Android

Tags: android, text, encoding

On android I'm obtaining data from a tab seperated text file, although I'm having trouble with a few things on the file.
First of which is the encoding, I read each line utilising `reader.readline()` but while doing this I get text which include xA0 characters that show up as diamonds with question marks in it on android.

I tried removing them with different types of `.replace("\\u00A0", "")`
As well as trying a reader that does

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), UTF8),BUFFER_SIZE);
```

None of these have removed the problem, I have a feeling it has something to do with reading it from a text file an how it gets read? But I'm not entirely sure, seems like everything I try to use just never works, no errors or bugs or anything, it just displays with that xA0 character.

I also have a second type of question that may impact the first. The text data itself has one part that seems to span multiple lines. For example I have 4 columns that are tab separated, and I obtain the value of each column on each line in code.
The problem is I find that on column 4, it spans multiple lines, and was wondering if there was a simple way to catch that into one line.
I ask this because excel seems to know that its part of the same column so I'm unsure if there is some easy encoding way to know it is or not?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it guys,

ended up using a buffered read utilising windows encoding as follows:

```
    //////////////////ENCODING CONVERT
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file.txt"), "windows-1252"));
```

Not sure if its the best way to do it, but I found the fix on another post on stackoverflow somewhere (I'll give credit if I find the post again)

For my second problem I ended up finding a work around by analysing an array I have. Thanks all.